# java read 200mb file, when load in memory, how much memory will need?

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory

I have a file with 200mb, the file with following format

each line is a spaced 0,1,2,3 integer.

> 0 1 2 0 1 3...

So, if I want to read this file into memory, should I be using array, using `Vector<Integer>`? or using `ByteArray`? or `String`?

How can I estimate the memory cost, so that can I set the java heap size appropriately? Would 256mb be enough?

Comment: the best way would be to profile the app. Try running "jvisualvm" on the command line.

Comment: I would avoid loading 200mb files into memory in general.  That is, you may be solving the wrong problem.

Comment: Meh; I don't have an issue with loading a 200M file in to memory--it totally depends on what you're actually trying to do with it, what the access pattern is, etc. Besides, depending on what's being done to it, the OS may be keeping it in memory anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For String size x 2 - String use char for each byte (you can set virtual machine flag to use byte)

```
-XX:+UseCompressedStrings   
   Use a byte[] for Strings which can be represented as pure ASCII. 
   (Introduced in Java 6 Update 21 Performance Release)
```

For List - count how many integer. For each integer it create one pointer to int (4 bytes or 8 bytes dependence on platform - you can set jvm option to use 32 bit address on 64 bit machine `-XX:+UseCompressedOops`)

Number of integers x ((size of one Integer) + (pointer to Integer in list)) = 2 * (number of integers) * (size of one pointer)

ByteBuffer - the same size like file

The best solution is primitive array - byte, short or int. It dependents of integer precision. For byte you have (number of int) bytes - can be less than file size.

Comment: I use Vector<Integer> to read the data, then it becomes 1.6G? which is eight times more. I understand that Integer object will take 16 bytes to represent one number, then it is 800m instead of 1.6G

Comment: See to file you have 0 1 2 0 1 3 - it is 12 bytes. It will be converted to 6 integers. 6 x 16 = 96 bytes. So you have 8 time more :)